# AS3 URLloader webpage then find and cut out everything else but one word?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, url

So, I load an external .html file into a urlloader and then make it to a string.

How do I now, for example in this string find and then cut out everything else than the word "Banana" for example?

**Im not trying to just remove "Banana" out of the string. Im trying to remove everything else but "Banana" out of the string.**

Answer (score 0):

```
var yourString:String = "Some string containing Banana and many other words.... blabla."
trace(yourString.split("Banana").join(""));
```

EDIT: Is this what you are trying to do?

```
var s:String = "http://www.abworddcwor.com/?p=dcwBanana13ordasd";
var word:String = "Banana";
if(s.indexOf(word) > -1) {
    trace(s.substr(s.indexOf(word) + word.length, 2));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that just remove the string "Banana" out of the whole loaded urlloader string? Because I can't seem to get it work in my code?

Comment: It does exactly that. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What's the purpose of it?

Comment: Im trying to remove everything else but "Banana" out of the string.

Comment: I got that. What for? Count the occurrences of "Banana" in the string and then create a new string with as many bananas as you had in the original...

Comment: I'm loading a web browser online game page where my health is display in %. I want to load this page in as3 with urlloader (or what can do this) then remove everything else but the string that says "health 13%" for example. And since I don't know the health value at the time I need to be able to find "health" and from there take the first value coming after. I'm thinking this maybe isnt possible in as3? Should I write my own api in php and then just use it with get data?